# Difference between writing bytes to a binary file and writing an decoded string to a unicode file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-unicode

This question might apply to more than Python, but that is the language I am using.

In Python 3, is there a difference between (1) writing bytes to a binary-encoded file and (2) decoding those bytes into a string and writing that to a regular unicode-encoded file?

Here's a code example.

```py
data = b'stuff'

# method (1)
with open('filename.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)

# method (2)
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data.decode())
```

**What is the difference if there is any?**

Thanks.

Comment: none as long as you are using the same encoding

Comment: Note, it isn't correct terminology to say that a file is "bytes encoded".

Comment: File mode `b` means "binary", not "bytes", but you do write bytes to a file in binary mode. As well, binary means there's no encoding.

Comment: Here's some related documentation if it helps: [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), [`bytes.decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode)

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga for the terminology clarification--I changed the question's phrasing.

Comment: And @wjandrea, the documentation clarified the issue a lot (didn't find those docs when I was googling).

Comment: Either one of you want to add an answer with that explanation, or at least reference the docs?